# How to identify if a text file is unix or windows using excel vba?

Tags: windows, vba, excel, unix

I need to process some files in Excel that may be in Unix or Windows format.  I already have the right code to read each one, but I need to know in advance the file type before calling the right procedure.

Is there an easy way to identify the file type (Unix / Windows) using VBA?

Thanks

Comment: Only thing I could guess is line endings... /r/n vs /n ? But I don't know about "excel files" unix vs windows

Comment: No, I'm talking about text files that may be in Unix or Windows format. I want to read them in Excel, but I need to know the file type before I call the right procedure.

Comment: Yeah then joser's answer is all I can think to do, unless your text files are special in some other way.

Comment: @RicardoFreire You could use the `FileSystemObject` to read in the entire file at once.  Then test it by trying to `Split` with `vbCrLf` (or `vbCR`) vs `vbLF`  Then process the resultant array.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10945779/loading-linux-text-file-into-excel-using-vba

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like this to count:

```
    Private Sub CountCRLF()
       Dim TmpStr$()
       TmpStr = Split(Text1.Text, Chr(13) & Chr(10))
       MsgBox "There are " & UBound(TmpStr()) & " CRLF's in string", vbInformation, "Count"
    End Sub
```

If that is more than a few, it should be a Windows file. If a file mixes both types of line breaks, a more complex approach would be needed.

But this worries me in terms of performance, unless you are sure the files are really small. And something in your question makes me think you already have a function to handle the lines one by one and you should probably try to only process these files once, detecting and handling as you go along...

Comment: The problem here is that I need to open the file and count the CR & LF's. I tried something like that:

`Sub ReadFile()
    Dim strText As String
    Dim strFile As String
    
    strFile = "textfile.csv"
    Open strFile For Input As #1
    Line Input #1, strText
    MsgBox "There are " & UBound(Split(strText, vbCrLf)) & " CRLF's in string", vbInformation, "Count"
    Close #1
End Sub`


If it's a unix file, the "Line Input" statement takes a long time. If it's a Windows file, the response is fast, but the line does not have a CRLF to split and count.

Comment: You can read the file in binary, then line endings won't make any difference. To read all of it, do `textData = Input$(LOF(#1), #1)`. I really hope your files are all small...

Comment: If it works don't forget to accept answer and upvote, I could use the rep : - )

Comment: I used a mix of your ideas to build a solution:

`Open strFile For Input As #1
 Input #1, strText
 Close #1
        
 If UBound(Split(strText, vbLf)) > 0 Then
     ReadUnixFile strFile
 Else
     ReadWindowsFile strFile
 End If`

In `ReadUnixFile` sub, I use the `Input$` statement, splitting the lines using vbLF as separator.

It's not a perfect solution, but it works.

By the way, my files have abou 160k lines, but the performance does not matter for now.

Thanks.

Comment: Hey Ricardo, please post your solution as another answer with formatting so the rest of us can benefit. Hard to follow as it is.