# Access using VBA to change a File Extension wtihout losing formatting

Tags: ms-access, text-files, file-extension

I am not sure that this can be done but I am working on a searchable database for the code for the machines I work on.  Basically its a C to VBA interpreter that allows me to quickly find all instances of a variable and move around the code easier to figure out what is going on when I get new versions of the code.  To do this I am renaming my C files to text files then using code to scan line by line and add variables, calls, ect.. to my database linking appropriate data.

My question is this when I change the extensions on the files manually from .c or .h to .txt the formatting doesn't change but when I use the VBA name function to copy the file and change the extension over to .txt I loose all white space formatting and instead of having 100 lines of code I end up with everything on a few lines.  Theoretically I should be able to still convert it all being on a couple of lines, but I am curious if anyone knows a different way to change the file extension through VBA without altering the format, basically just renames the file without any other alterations.  I have tried both the Name function and the FileCopy functions but they both end up removing all white space and putting all the code on a couple of lines.

Thanks for any help on this one.

-Zak

Comment: Your source files are obviously in UNIX format (Lf only), while Windows expects CrLf for line breaks. But how a manual rename / extension change would modify that eludes me... -- Are you perhaps opening the files with a text editor (that understands UNIX format) and then save them as txt? That might convert them to Windows format.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41830959/how-to-identify-if-a-text-file-is-unix-or-windows-using-excel-vba and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10945779/loading-linux-text-file-into-excel-using-vba

Comment: Well I use Notepad to view the file afterward just to see what I am working with, but like I said if I manually rename the file by changing the name from Example.c to Example.txt I can view the C file as a text file and all the spacing stays the same but if I use either procedure I mentioned above to change the extension it kills all the white space in the text file for some reason.

Comment: If I don't change the extension from .c to .txt then only the first line gets read in when I read it in as a text file using the Open exampleFileName For Input As #ifile command.

Comment: I still don't quite understand what's going on. But I suggest you install [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/), it shows the file format in its status bar (right hand side).