# Why is the result 1, when I count the lines of the text?

Tags: excel, count, line, vba

Originally I have a list of name of text files in the column A (in excel), and I want to go through all files to open and count its rows. When I run the script below the counter result is '**1**'

When I open the text files with Notepad++ or Sublime Text I see the lines of the file in different rows. But when I open the files with Notepad I see whole text in one row. What is the problem in this case and how can I fix it. (The line divider is '**LF**'.)

```
Sub counting()

    Dim FilePath As String
    Dim counter As Integer
    Dim curLine As String

    FilePath = "C:\Users\kornel.fekete\Desktop\test\Test.txt"

    Open FilePath For Input As #1

    Do While Not EOF(1)
        counter = counter + 1
        Line Input #1, curLine
    Loop

    Cells(1, 1).Value = counter

    Close #1

End Sub
```

I have to do this counting with more than 100 text files.

Comment: your sub `counter` has the same name as your variable `counter` which is no good idea. And there is a `Next i` without a `For` loop?

Comment: `Open FilePath For Input` does only recognize `CRLF` but not `LF` as line breaks. • Possible duplicate of [Loading linux text file into excel using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10945779/loading-linux-text-file-into-excel-using-vba)

Comment: My bad, the copy-paste was wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a textstream:

```
Sub counting()

    Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
    Dim ts As TextStream
    Dim longtext As String
    Dim lines As Variant

    Set ts = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\kornel.fekete\Desktop\test\Test.txt", ForReading, False)
    longtext = ts.ReadAll
    ts.Close
    lines = Split(longtext, vbLf)
    Cells(1, 1) = UBound(lines) - LBound(lines) + 1

End Sub
```

You need to set a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime.