# Extract data from syslog file in vba

Tags: excel, vba

With below code, I'm trying to extract a line from syslog file having string `original value` but I'm getting whole file data as output.

```
Sub test()
Dim InputData

' Open file for input.
Open "D:\temp\DraftTest3_pmi_jt_import_All_Annotations.syslog" For Input As #1 

Do While Not EOF(1) ' Check for end of file.
    Line Input #1, InputData    ' Read line of data.
    Debug.Print InputData    ' Print to the Immediate window.
    If InStr(1, InputData, "original value") Then
        Cells(2, 3).Value = InputData ''' Print a line in cell
        InputData = ""
    End If
Loop

Close #1    ' Close file.
End Sub
```

Syslog content:

```
Nodes differ : original value 189.1596739640256
               new value      191.1200796864099

Difference: 

<object type="NXOpen.ValidationAnnotation3DCollectionValidator" value="None" xml_line_number="14" />
 <context line_number="132" variable_name="validationAnnotation3DCollectionValidator1" xml_line_number="15" />
  <object type="NXOpen.ValidationWeldValidator" value="None" xml_line_number="2675" />
   <context line_number="0" variable_name="" xml_line_number="2676" />
    <output name="WeldReferenceLineLength" xml_line_number="2677" />
      <object tolerance="1e-06" tolerance_type="absolute" type="double" value="189.1596739640256" />

      *** changed to ***

      <object tolerance="1e-06" tolerance_type="absolute" type="double" value="191.1200796864099" xml_line_number="2678" />
_________________________________________________________________________________________

Nodes differ : original value 102.5546050485778
               new value      102.8898888970786

Difference: 

<object type="NXOpen.ValidationAnnotation3DCollectionValidator" value="None" xml_line_number="14" />
 <context line_number="132" variable_name="validationAnnotation3DCollectionValidator1" xml_line_number="15" />
  <object type="NXOpen.ValidationWeldValidator" value="None" xml_line_number="4422" />
   <context line_number="0" variable_name="" xml_line_number="4423" />
    <output name="WeldReferenceLineLength" xml_line_number="4424" />
      <object tolerance="1e-06" tolerance_type="absolute" type="double" value="102.5546050485778" />
```

Desired output:

[image]

Comment: InStr returns a Variant, not a Boolean - I think you need `If InStr(...) > 0`

Comment: `If InStr(1, InputData, "original value") > 0 Then` same output.

Comment: OK- what do you mean by "getting whole file data as output"?  You will still see every line on the debug console because the Print is not within the If.

Comment: Seeing whole content in a cell.

Comment: Do you want to extract the value `189.1596739640256`?

Comment: Yes. I want that value.

Comment: Then simply use `SPLIT` twice and you will get the value. ;) Let me give an exmaple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do you want to extract the value 189.1596739640256? – Siddharth Rout 7 mins ago
>
> Yes. I want that value. – Experimenter 6 mins ago

The fastest way to get that value would be

1. Open and read the text file in ONE GO. i.e without looping
2. Split on `original value`
3. And then split on `new value`

**Code:**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim MyData As String, ValueNeeded As String

    '~~> Change this to the relevant file
    '~~> Read the entire file in a variable in ONE GO
    Open "C:\Users\routs\Desktop\Sample.Txt" For Binary As #1
    MyData = Space$(LOF(1))
    Get #1, , MyData
    Close #1

    ValueNeeded = Trim(Split(MyData, "original value")(1))
    ValueNeeded = Trim(Split(ValueNeeded, "new value")(0))

    Debug.Print ValueNeeded
End Sub
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

**EDIT**

To incorporate multiple instances as shown in your recent edit, you will have to look for a unique word. In your case it would be `Nodes differ :`. Why this? becuase this signifies a new section. So the logic would be to split on `Nodes differ :` and then split on `original value`, `new value` and `Difference:`

See this example

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim MyData As String, ValueString As String
    Dim orgVal As String, newVal As String
    Dim strData() As String
    Dim i As Long

    '~~> Change this to the relevant file
    '~~> Read the entire file in a variable in ONE GO
    Open "C:\Users\routs\Desktop\test.Txt" For Binary As #1
    MyData = Space$(LOF(1))
    Get #1, , MyData
    Close #1

    '~~> Split on "Nodes differ :" to identify separate sections
    '~~> Store them in an array
    strData() = Split(MyData, "Nodes differ :")

    '~~> Loop though each section and split on relevant identifiers
    '~~> to get the necessary value
    For i = LBound(strData) + 1 To UBound(strData)
        ValueString = Trim(Split(strData(i), "original value")(1))
        orgVal = Trim(Split(ValueString, "new value")(0))
        newVal = Trim(Split(ValueString, "new value")(1))
        newVal = Trim(Split(newVal, "Difference:")(0))

        Debug.Print "Original Value: " & Trim(orgVal)
        Debug.Print "New Value: " & Trim(newVal)
    Next i
End Sub
```

[image]

**NOTE:** I have not done any error handling. I am sure you will take care of that...

Comment: So I can use it at any line and for extracting any string from line?

Comment: Yes if the lookup value is not getting repeated. For example if there are two lines which have the text `"original value"`, then you will have to handle that accordingly. If there is only one instance of it then yes you can use the above approach.

Comment: I would have that bunch of lines repeated so want to handle this case.

Comment: If you show a sample then maybe i can give you a better advice :)

Comment: This is all in one text file or different text files??

Comment: This is all in one text file. 1st row has the string which exists in the line.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197867/discussion-between-siddharth-rout-and-experimenter).

Answer (score 1):

InStr returns a Variant, not a Boolean.  Try changing your comparison to `If InStr(...) > 0`.  Docs are at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/instr-function .

I also note that you are overwriting a single cell with each value in turn.  If you want to save all the values, you will need to change how you index `Cells`.

**Edit** `Line Input` cannot handle Unix-type text files (LF-only line endings).  See, e.g., https://chandoo.org/forum/threads/line-input-reads-entire-text-file-as-a-single-record.23089/ .  Try the answers at [Loading linux text file into excel using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10945779/2877364) .  In short, you have to read the whole file (which you already do :) ) and then split it on `vbLf` to get individual lines.