# How do I convert a file with unix line endings to DOS using VBA (Excel) for large files (larger than 1GB) and do so quickly?

Tags: excel, vba, windows

I was able to get the higher rated answer (Alex K.) working to revise smaller files than the file I want to convert (1.7Gb) from here:

[Loading linux text file into excel using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10945779/loading-linux-text-file-into-excel-using-vba)

I think using the Buffer has a memory limitation or I'm getting an error I wasn't expecting for large UNIX format files.

This problem has plagued me for sometime, and I usually just use Notepad++ and Edit→EOL conversion→Windows, but I'd like to be able to convert the file native to Excel so that my other,  more complex, programs can work properly.

My files for those other programs aren't always UNIX carriage returns, but when they are, it throws a user error. Sometimes the user may not understand the work around (fix).

If the solution takes much much longer than Notepad++ or using unix2dos in linux then maybe I have to continue with those alternatives, but I'd really prefer a way to do this in EXCEL VBA.

Thanks in advance!

***EDIT***
: I'm adding the code I have, that works for files less than 1GB in size. Perhaps someone can fix it or poke holes at the approach (I think reading the whole file into memory throws an error and line by line doesn't seem possible that I know of). This code roughly takes 10 minutes for a test file I had which is just short of 1GB (14,581,137 lines):

```
Sub unix2Dos()

Dim FName As Variant
Dim myfilename As String
Dim FNum As Integer
Dim chars As Integer
Dim StartTime As Date, EndTime As Date
FNum = FreeFile
Dim FSO As Object
Set FSO = VBA.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set fs2 = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")


FName = Application.GetOpenFilename _
(filefilter:="All Files (*.*),*.*,Text Files(*.txt),*.txt,Bulk Files(*.bdf),*.bdf,Bulk Files(*.blk),*.blk,Bulk Files(*.bulk),*.bulk,Control Decks(*.dat),*.dat,")
If FName = False Then
MsgBox "You didn't select a file", vbCritical
Exit Sub
End If

On Error GoTo user_interupt

If FileExists(FName) Then
    Set f = fs2.GetFile(FName)
    filesize1 = f.Size / 1024 'in Kb
Else
    filesize1 = 0
End If

    If filesize1 >= 1048576 Then
    MsgBox "File Size too large for this VBA to handle, please Convert to DOS another way. For Notepad++ go to Edit->EOL conversion->Windows." & Chr(13) & _
    "Or Ultra Edit go to Advanced->Conversions->Unix/Mac (Legacy) to Dos" & Chr(13) & _
    "Or in Linux, Cygwin, or Unix Environment from the comand line use this command:> unix2dos filename"
    ElseIf filesize1 < 1048576 Then
    StartTime = Timer
    
    Open FName For Input As #1
    '//load all
    buff = Input$(LOF(1), #1)
    Close #1
    
    
    chars = Len(FName)
    If Right(FName, 3) = "bdf" Then
    myfilename = (Left(FName, chars - 4)) & "_DOS.bdf"
    ElseIf Right(FName, 4) = "bulk" Then
    myfilename = (Left(FName, chars - 5)) & "_DOS.bulk"
    ElseIf Right(FName, 3) = "txt" Then
    myfilename = (Left(FName, chars - 4)) & "_DOS.txt"
    ElseIf Right(FName, 3) = "blk" Then
    myfilename = (Left(FName, chars - 4)) & "_DOS.blk"
    ElseIf Right(FName, 3) = "dat" Then
    myfilename = (Left(FName, chars - 4)) & "_DOS.dat"
    Else
    myfilename = FName & "_DOS.txt"
    End If
    
    Open myfilename For Output Access Write As #FNum
    '//Use Below; Testing showed very little distance in compute time
    'buff = Replace$(buff, vbLf, vbCrLf)
    '   Print #FNum, buff
    
    '//*or* line by line
    Dim lines() As String: lines = Split(buff, vbLf)
    For i = 0 To UBound(lines)
    'MsgBox lines(i)
    Print #FNum, lines(i)
    Next
    
    Close #FNum
    
    EndTime = Timer
    
    MsgBox "Unix2Dos: File Converted From UNIX to DOS " & Chr(13) & _
    "If your file had a mix of Carriage returns (DOS AND UNIX), " & Chr(13) & _
    "then you may have undesired blanks " & Chr(13) & _
    " Run Time  : " & Strings.Format(EndTime - StartTime, "0.0") & " sec"
    End If



user_interupt:
If Err = 0 Then
'do nothing
Else:
    MsgBox "The most recent error number is " & Err & _
    ". Its message text is: " & Error(Err)
End If

End Sub

Public Function FileExists(ByVal FileToTest As String) As Boolean
   FileExists = (Dir(FileToTest) <> "")
End Function
```

Comment: Massively reduce the amount of i/o by reading all (or chunks) of the file with `input$()` instead of line-by-line with `line input` then `replace$()` to swap the line endings & write back to disk.

Comment: I think I don't understand your suggestion. I'm a self taught coder in vba, but as I understand it, reading in Line by line gives the whole file (1.7Gb) at a time (assuming the file is Unix CR) and is too big to split into smaller chunks? Can you post a solution in Code as an answer that I can try? Not trying to be ungrateful here. I do appreciate a response.